# Why is my mapped DTO List null? What is the best way to map and persist Child Lists?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, modelmapper

I have a simple problem - but I think "I am standing on the tube".
I have a spring boot rest api with JPA, Modelmapper, Entities and DTOs.
But the mapping doesn't work.

Entities:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@MappedSuperclass
public class AbstractEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity(name = "contacts")
public class Contact extends AbstractEntity {
  @NotBlank
  private String firstName;
  @NotBlank
  private String lastName;
  @Valid
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "contact", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumberList;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity(name = "phone_numbers")
public class PhoneNumber extends AbstractEntity {
  @NotBlank
  private String label;
  @NotBlank
  private String number;
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "contact_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  @Setter(value = AccessLevel.NONE)
  private Contact contact;
}
```

The DTOs:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ContactDTO {
  private Long id;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  List<PhoneNumberDTO> phoneNumberDTOList = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PhoneNumberDTO {
  private Long id;
  private String label;
  private String number;
}
```

My ModelMapperConfig:

```
  @Bean
  public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    modelMapper.getConfiguration()
        .setFieldMatchingEnabled(true)
        .setFieldAccessLevel(AccessLevel.PRIVATE);
    return modelMapper;
  }
```

Repo:

```
public interface ContactRepository extends JpaRepository<Contact, Long{
}
```

Service (only the create method):

```
  @Override
  public ContactDTO createOne(ContactDTO contactDTO) {
    Contact contact = modelMapper.map(contactDTO, Contact.class);
    contactRepository.save(contact);
    return contactDTO;
  }
```

Is this the correct way to persist the Contact with its multiple phonenumbers?

And how can I create a simple mapping?

If i want to persist it, there comes an error:

```
Column 'contact_id' cannot be null
```

Comment: You haven't posted any code showing how you persist contacts, so we can't tell you if the code persisting contacts is correct. It's certainly not, since you get an error. But we can't tell why you have that error, since you didn't post the code, and since you posted a tiny portion of the exception stack trace. If you think that what is problematic is the "automatic" mapping, and you don't understand what it does, then get rid of it, and write the few trivial, easy to understand, lines of code allowing to transform the DTOs into entities.

Comment: sorry, I added some other snippets now

Comment: Inspect your PhoneNumber entities: their contact field is null. And it can't be. hence the error. You need to set the contact of each PhoneNumber before saving them.

Comment: yes but the problem is, I get the contact id after saving the contact (mysql auto_increment). so I have to do it with 2 repositories (first save contact, then get id, then save phone numbers) but I think that isn't a nice version.

Comment: No. You have the contact alreay. You're saving it. That contact that you're saving must be set as the contact of the phone numbers. Even if the contact isn't saved yet.

Comment: yes but the contact id is missing (because is is auto incremented by the database)

Comment: No. It's missing because you haven't set the contact field of the PhoneNumber entities. Why don't you at least do what I suggest and test my solution, before claiming I'm incorrect?

Comment: Ok perhaps i dont understand you. So can you please post a code snippet? I didnt say you are incorrect! I only said that i dont have the contact_id before saving a contact.

Comment: `contact.getPhoneNumberList().forEach(phoneNumber -> phoneNumber.setContact(contact));`. That sets the contact field of every PhoneNumber.

Comment: it only works when I post the contact id in my request body. but that isn't the behavior I want. the client don't know the id on a POST, because the database does an auto increment